# How to find the P-Value for this test of hypothesis?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I so we started a new section where I need to identify the (Null hypothesis, alternative hypothesis, test statistic, and p-value) I found all the information expect the p-value I couldn't understand my professor when he explained it.

So here's the problem.

Ex:In a recent poll of 755 randomly selected adults, 587 said that it is morally wrong to not report all income on tax returns. Use a 0.05 significance level to test the claim that 75​% of adults say that it is morally wrong to not report all income on tax returns. Identify the null​ hypothesis, alternative​ hypothesis, test​ statistic, P-value, conclusion about the null​ hypothesis, and final conclusion that addresses the original claim. Use the​ P-value method. Use the normal distribution as an approximation of the binomial distribution.

I found most of the information this is what I have: $p = .75\;$
$\hat p = x/n,$ which gives you .777;
$q = .25,\;$
$n = 755,\;$ and
$x = 587.$

The significance level is 0.05, and I found the test statistic: its 1.71.
I used the following formula

$$z = ( \hat p - p)/\sqrt{.75(.25)/755} = 1.71.$$

The one I missing is the p-value which I don't how to obtain.
I know that this is a two tail test however this is the part I'm stuck on.
Could anyone share their expertise with me so I may learn to do it on my own?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I like the phrasing of your question in general. I highly suggest you use MathJax/LaTeX markup, because people tend to complain otherwise, and it does make the questions more readable.

Comment: Thank you ill check it out to see how to write Latex Notation!

Comment: I have edited your Question to include some TeX formatting. Please check whether I have changed your intended meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for including some preliminary computations. You have $\hat p = 587/755  = 0.7775.$ You want to test $H_0: p = .75,$
perhaps against the 2-sided alternative $H_a: p \ne .75.$

**Two-sided test.** The test statistic is $$Z = \frac{\hat p - .75}{\sqrt{(.75)(.25)/755}} = 1.744,$$
which should be approximately standard normal if $H_0$ is true.
You'd reject $H_0$ at the 5% level, if $|Z| > 1.96,$ which is not
true, so you don't reject.

The P-value is the probability of a more extreme result than that observed.
For a two-sided hypothesis, that means 'more extreme in either direction',
so the P-value is 
$$P(|Z| > 1.744) = 1 - P(|Z| \le 1.774) = 1 - P(-1.744 \le Z \le 1.744).$$
Using software, I got about $0.08,$ but you should compute it using
normal tables or whatever software you're expected to use in your class.

**Right-sided test.** If you were supposed to test against the *one-sided* alternative $H_a: p > .75,$
then you'd reject if $Z > 1.645,$ which *is* true. So you would reject $H_0.$
(You know that the estimate $\hat p > .75$, the question is whether it is
*significantly* larger, or whether .7775 could have just have happened
to exceed .75 due to random sampling error.)

For the right-tailed test, the P-value is
$P(Z > 1.774),$ the probability of a more extreme value *in the direction of*
the alternative. That P-value is half as big as for the two-sided test.

---

*Note:* You say you are doing a two-sided test. Not knowing the context of the problem, I can't say for sure that is right. So I'll let you
think about that as required.

(Suppose the purpose of the poll were to asses
the chances of passage of Proposition A in an upcoming election, and it
takes 75% Yes votes for passage. Then I'd suppose you'd want a one-sided
test. If lore from previous years is that 75% of the population thinks
it's morally wrong to cheat on income tax, and the purpose of the poll
is to assess whether that opinion has *changed* recently (one way or the other), then I'd suppose
you want a two-sided alternative.)

---

**Sketches.** In problems like this, it is always a good idea to draw
sketches so you can visualize the areas that match various probabilities.

In the left panel below (two-sided alternative), the heavy black line is the
observed value of $Z,$ the dotted black line is just as far from 0 as the
heavy black line, and the P-value is the sum of the two areas beyond the
black lines. The rejection region is values of $Z$ between the two red bars
(at 'critical values'); the total area under the density curve and outside the two red bars is 5%.

In the right panel (right-sided alternative), the heavy black line is again
the observed value of $Z.$ The red line is at the critical value, and 5% of
the area under the density curve to the right of the red bar. The rejection
region is to the right of the red line, and the observed value of $Z$ is
in the rejection region. The P-value (smaller than 5%) is the area to the
right of the observed value of $Z$.

[image]